# Can i test iphone application using selenium webdriver?

Tags: iphone, selenium, testing, automation

I am working with selenium webdriver and performed automation for Web application and Android Application. 
Can Anyone tell how can i test Iphone Application using Selenium Webdriver ??
Are there any specific jars for that ??

Please share any link for automating iphone application!!

Comment: Use [Appium](http://appium.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test iPhone application using Selenium Webdriver.
However you can use [Appium](http://appium.io/) for automating iOS applications.
You can use iOS Driver alongwith Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode itself have the Testing tools and you can use the same. For that go to Instruments and select Automation or else you can use the APPIUM Server and its inspector.